# Is "go" an acceptable pro-verb for "be (at a specific place)"?

Tags: verbs, pro-verb-constructions

I'm the TA for an ancient philosophy class. A student used the following sentence in his paper.

> Accordingly, Anaxagoras believes that the movement we observe  is the effect of the cosmos’ guiding intelligence moving its constituents to wherever it judges they ought to *go*.

I expected to see *be* in place of *go*. I considered the sentence, and concluded that I preferred *go* over *be*. However, I don't know whether formal English allows writers to use *go* as the student did.

Did the student use *go* grammatically?

(The answer won't affect his grade.)

Comment: I think it's General Reference that **be*** and ***go*** are both valid in this exact context, and any "preference" is entirely a matter of opinion.

Comment: You think that it's a general reference question? I've read a few usage guides, and I don't recall reading about it.

Comment: If that implies you're not a native speaker, you should be posting on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I would expect all competent native speakers to know that both forms are valid, regardless of how easy it is for you to "look it up".

Comment: I ought to go to Paris. I ought to be in Paris. Paris is where I ought to go. Paris is where I ought to be. This isn't a matter of dodgy grammar, but of not recognising different equally acceptable descriptions of an event / final state, one emphasising the process, the other the final state.

Comment: On the other hand, what do you mean by "Is 'go' an acceptable **pro-verb** "? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb) covers very different entities. You probably mean 'alternative', or perhaps 'synonym'.

Comment: Wheneve an event of _going_ has been completed, the agent subject of _go_ is located in a different place from the place where it was when it started. Consequently, _go_ is the causative of the locative sense of _be_ (_go to Indianapolis => be in Indianapolis_). It's not true that _go_ means the same as _be_; _be_ has no meaning and is predictable as an auxiliary verb. Rather _go_ **entails** a change in location, and therefore a locative _be_ may be used to express the change. (_Go_ is, of course, [**much** more complex than this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf).)

Answer (score 2):

*Go* is not a substitute for *be*. However, either is acceptable in this context, depending on which of two different metaphors the writer might be using: that of being in a place or that of going to a place.

Comment: I can't see anything metaphorical here. Weird beliefs, maybe.

Comment: Sorry, @EdwinAshworth, you're right. I didn't go back and reread the question: it does appear to be meant literally.

Answer (score 1):

In **this** case, *go* is exactly equivalent to *be,* because there is an extra *to* in the sentence.

> ... moving things **to** wherever they ought to go. [Simplified sentence]

It's the same as someone carefully sorting through objects, "This goes here, that goes over there..." — *wherever* references the final position of the cosmos' constituents.

Without that *to* in the sentence, the meaning changes subtly:

> ... moving things wherever they ought to go.
>   ... moving things wherever they ought to be.

The first describes the movement: the guiding intelligence is mapping out the path each thing should take through the cosmos, like a child on the floor with a toy car.

The second describes the results of the movement: the guiding intelligence is making sure things are in the right place. Note that including *to* here doesn't alter that meaning.

Comment: I'm not entirely happy that *moving things wherever they ought to be* means the same as the same with *to* inserted. Doesn't the first have a flavour of "moving things, no matter where they should be"?

Comment: @TimLymington It can have that sense, but it can have the other one too.